# What are all the features required for a Quantum theory of gravity?

Tags: quantum-gravity, theory-of-everything

I do understand why are we seeking Theory of Quantum Gravity. What I am specifically asking is if there was a Theory of Quantum Gravity what would be its key features. Such as when would it be considered "complete". Like do we need the field equations and so on..

Comment: Renormalizability would be a key feature, that is missing in the current theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: The theory should give classical General Relativity (probably with *torsion* included) under a proper limit, and Quantum Mechanics (or Quantum Field Theory) under another non-trivial limit.  It should explain the true nature and origin of the Big Bang (without singularities), and describe what happen to matter and spacetime at the center of any black hole.  It should explain why space have three macroscopic dimensions, while time has just one.  I don't believe such a theory could ever be mathematically formulated, and be understandable by humans!  Better believe in unicorns and magic.